# Preventing flash from loading on undesired pages while using Rails and Turbo Links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have a problem with my flash message lingering on pages that I don't want it to appear on.

I'm using Rails 4 with turbo links.

While I very much like turbo links, I think it might be the problem here.

In my rails controller I'm setting the desire flash as follows:

```
def show
     if item.status == "In Progress" || item.status == "draft"
            flash[:alert] = "Please remember: the status of this text is draft. You have been granted access through the generosity of the editor. Please use the comments to help make suggestions or corrections."
     end
 end
```

But then, when I click a link and turbo links responsively loads a new page, the flash appears again.

Any ideas about how to prevent this while continuing to use turbolinks

Comment: use flash.now[:alert], it will not be available to the next action, only to the current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either clear the flash message in  before_action in the application controller
In application_controller.rb

```
before_action :clear_flash

def clear_flash
  flash.discard
end
```

Or simply use change your code to:

```
def show
 if item.status == "In Progress" || item.status == "draft"
        flash.now[:alert] = "Please remember: the status of this text is draft. You have been granted access through the generosity of the editor. Please use the comments to help make suggestions or corrections."
 end    
end
```